# Solr spatial search advanced! Solr field value in the query? Solr 4.10

Tags: solr

Let's say we have solr document representing building with multiple location fields. Every building document has at least one location, which indicates building's location. While all others location fields are dynamic, and represents facilities around the building.

Let's say that these facilities are type based, for an example; 1 - schools, 2 - parks, 3 - parking lots.

Therefore each building may have variety of these facilities, some of the buildings may be pointing to the same type facility and same location, while others may have pointing same type, but with different location.

In essence we have:

```
building: {
...
main_location: "lat:long",
facility_1_location: "lat:long",
facility_2_location: "lat:long",
...
}
```

How to construct query, if we want to find all buildings that have facility of type "schools" or "1" with 5 kilometers radius?

One potential solution is to make sub queries, while each sub-query takes `main_location` of the building and queries against `facility_1_location`, however query will grow in size very repeatedly if we have a lot of building to store.

Another solution, would be to use documents itself field as `main_location` to construct query, but I am not sure if that's possible in Solr. Tried and searched for it, but I couldn't find a solution.

Are there any experts on this? I am using Solr 4.10

Comment: Use a single document for each building?